# C++: Comparing strings or wstrings with special characters in them (á, é, ő, etc.)

Tags: c++, string, char, wchar-t, wstring

I recently got an assignment that requires me to compare words. I don't want to describe it in full, but I have to compare the words character-by-character to see how similar two words are.

Now the problem is that the input text I have to use contains a lot of non-standard characters like á, é, ő, etc. I tried using string, wstring, char and wchar_t for representing my words, but nothing seems to work properly. An example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

std::vector <Word::Word> words;

std::wfstream fileWrite("testout.txt");
std::wstring s = words[0].getString();

fileWrite << s;
```

Our string contains the word "Még" here. It outputs correctly. For the record, everything works the same if I use string instead of wstring. The following works too:

```
const wchar_t* wc = s.c_str();
fileWrite << wc;
```

But as soon as I try referencing to a char it gives me gibberish. Example:

```
fileWrite << wc[0] << " " << wc[1];
```

This outputs "ď »". I'm guessing the problem is that they use multiple bytes to store a char? I'm just wildly guessing here, but that would explain why

```
wcslen(wc);
```

returns 7.

I tried using the substr function with both string and wstring, but generally doesn't seem to be working. Anyone has any idea on how to tackle this problem? Am I missing something obvious here?

Also, I'm using codeblocks with a gcc compiler, I've read it somewhere that it doesn't handle wchar and wstring well, could that be the problem? Remember, I've tried everything above with string instead of wstring, and it was the same.

Thank you all very much for the help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the input encoding, and output encoding?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% sure. I've received a txt file to work on, and I don't know how to check the encoding of that. However, I did copy it to another one and used "Save as..." to save it with UTF-8.

That should mean that it is UTF-8 encoding and the "original" doesn't matter, right?

Comment: The assignment is not well-defined if the encoding is not known. Once you know the encoding you'll have to look into unicode. This is not an easy problem.

Comment: Sorry for being lame here, I've never worked with texts before. Can you suggest an easy way to check the encoding? 
I'll jump on google in the meanwhile.

Comment: .txt files do not store the encoding they were saved in. You can _assume_ that they are UTF-8, but that'd be an assumption.

Comment: I understand that it's important. I've opened the file in Notepad++ and that tells me it is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: And I've opened the original file in Notepad++ and it says ANSI.

Comment: So, to clear up the confusion: I have an original file which is gigantic. I copied the first couple of lines into a new text file so I can test my program easily. I've saved the new text file with "Save as" and selected UTF-8, HOWEVER, the original file has ANSI encoding.

Comment: You don't understand. The .txt file __does not store the encoding__. Notepad++ is just guessing. Ask your professor what encoding the file is in, because anything else is just an assumption.

Comment: Open your file in a text editor and check "encoding" in the menu. It looks like your encoding is UTF-8. It will **not** work by default on Windows. You will have to jump through some hoops. The easiest way is to recode the file to UTF-16 and use wide character functions throughout. The hard way is to stay with UTF-8, read to `char` strings, then convert to `wchar_t` strings with non-standard Windows-specific functions (standard ones probably don't work on Windows).   BTW these characters are neither special nor non-standard in any way. It's Windows that is special and non-standard.

Comment: There's no such thing as "ANSI encoding", or rather "ANSI encoding" is a sloppy term that denotes way too many things which have other, proper names. Notepad++ is wrong to ever display this word.

Comment: Hey n.m.! orlp points out a bit further up that notepad++ doesn't necessarily know the encoding? I have no idea if he's right or not tho. I explained it a few comments back what Encoding says in the menu. About the second part of your comment tho, I did convert the strings to wchar_t strings... didn't I? Doesn't seem to be working this way :\

Comment: That's great, then I'm truly lost :D

Comment: I used notepad++'s "Convert to UTF-8" function and at a quick glance there seems to be some improvement. Please let me test it a bit more and then I'll get back to you guys!

Comment: "notepad++ doesn't necessarily know the encoding" that's true. It is guessing the encoding from the first few dozen characters. No it didn't convert to wchar_t correctly. There's about zillion ways to do it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

These characters are not unusual. They are absolutely standard Unicode characters. Unfortunately, plain standard C++ doesn't have any support for the finer details of Unicode. Your choice is to either find a nice library supporting it (for example for code running on MacOS X or iOS you would just use what's built into the OS, other operating systems might have similar support), or to go to www.unicode.org and download their code tables. And read everything you can find out about it.

wchar and wstring are inherently non-portable. Your best bet is to use UTF-8 encoding and standard std::string. And understanding UTF-8 is absolutely essential for any programmer nowadays.

There was some discussion here about Notepad. Lots of software writes UTF-8 preceded by a byte-order marker (BOM) and lots of software uses that to recognise UTF-8. If that byte order marker is not present, they look at individual bytes. There is a possibility that a file consists only of ASCII characters, in which case it doesn't matter what encoding it is. If it's not only ASCII, the likelihood that for example a Windows-1252 encoded file containing non-ASCII characters is legal UTF-8 is practically zero.

Comment: It should also be noted that the Windows console is not UTF-8 by default, for some reason.

Comment: "use UTF-8 encoding and standard std::string" The problem here is that UTF-8 strings do not decompose to "characteres" easily, which seems to be the OP's goal. The easiest (by far) method of working with Unicode is keeping everything as UCS-4 internally, and converting to/from whatever encoding that is in use externally.

Comment: n.m. sees it right. I converted the input file to UTF-8, since then it works with wstring but not quite properly for string (I can't get individual letters without conversion to wstring or wchar_t). When you say it is non-portable, you mean it will be windows-only, or are there further restrictions? Also, n.m., I don't even understand what you are saying about "converting to UCS-4 internally". Can you post me a link here so I can read up on the subject? Thanks for all the help guys.